# Как создать комнату для чата 1 на 1 для Firebase web progressive app?

Tags: firebase, push-уведомления, chat

Я создаю простое веб-прогрессивное приложение - список пользователей и видеочат один на один (tokbox) + текстовый чат.
Рабочий процесс следующий: пользователь регистрируется с gmail или fb> пользователь видят список онлайн-пользователей> пользователь входят в профиль пользователя> пользователь может нажать кнопку вызова.

После нажатия кнопки `call` ответчик онлайн-пользователя должен быть уведомлен с помощью push-уведомления и одобрить создание чата, который будет создан сразу после подтверждения пользователем push-сообщения.

Вопрос в том, что я не нашел ни одного примера или документации для облачных сообщений Firebase (FCM), что push-уведомление может вызывать какие-либо функции (я так понимаю на событие одобрения пользователем я и создаю комнату и делаю редирект юзера), а не просто информационное сообщение.

Нужен пример подобной реализации или понимать последовательность действий для данной задачи, пожалуйста

Comment: Переведите, пожалуйста, вопрос на русский язык.